# WD Elements Desktop External - Not recognised on a single computer

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

My WD Elements Desktop External is no longer recognized on my main computer.

It has worked fine in the past, but now all of a sudden is not detected. It does not prompt when plugged in, nor does it show up in the disc management interface or the device manager. It appears to be aware that it is plugged in however as the light on the external blinks rapidly for a short while after being plugged in.

The strangest thing however is that it works fine on other computers, including my family computers and my laptop.

I have attempted to troubleshoot the issue by trying various USB devices in multiple ports on each system to see if there is any correlation with the issue, but have come up with nothing that gives me an idea of what is going on.

I have also attempted to format the external using my laptop, but that has not helped either.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is detected in bios. If yes, then go to device manager right click on entry corresponding to your external and uninstall. After that reboot and see if it is getting listed.

Comment: Under what area would I be looking for the external? My bios doesn't seem to have a section for individual USB drives.

Comment: It will be under either boot device priority or hard disk drives. There is another shortcut method, bring in the boot device selection menu. Most probably f11 f10 or f12. In it all devices will be listed.

Comment: Boot device selection offers my internal harddrive, CD drive and removable drive as options.
I believe removable drive is always displayed regardless of having one plugged in though, and it does not offer more information

Comment: Ok. In some Motherboards, Device is also shown, That is why i asked. Any way try deleting external HD from device manager and reboot.

Comment: On my laptop the external is displayed under disc drives as WD Ext HDD 1021 USB Device, with USB Mass Storage Device appearing under USB Controllers.
Neither of these two appear when plugged into my computer, so I am unable to delete it.

Comment: I will check and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: Hi. Check if under usb controllers in device manager, usb mass storage is listed. Delete them all and restart.

Comment: It was listed when plugging in my iPod. I deleted it and restarted the computer and nothing occurred until I plugged my iPod back in, at which point the USBMassStorage controller reinstalled. This did not however affect my external.

Comment: Try ubuntu live cd and check if your drive is detected.

Comment: My external was not detected using Ubuntu, but my iPod was.

Comment: Then the problem is with your computer's hardware. Did you change your bios version? older versions may not detect terabyte HDs.

Comment: No. I have had no changes to my system at all besides updating the video games I play. I would except a hardware fault to be the case except other externals and USB devices work fine, it is rather curious.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for your problem ? http://www.topnotchtablets.com/files/USBDeview-32bit.zip  Download this and uninstall every device and then restart and check if it helps... I got it from here http://www.topnotchtablets.com/FixUSBproblems